# DEPLOYED MATLAB FILE DOES NOT START

Tags: matlab

Please, I have this piece of code that involves saving state of gui (using Doug Hull's) approach. 
The problem is the script compiles alright but only pops up and vanishes when I run it, using deploytool. I am using Matlab R2012b.

```
function savestate3

S.fh=figure('NumberTitle','off',...
    'Visible','on','Position',[360 400 450 285],...
    'closerequestfcn',{@fh_crfcn});


S.tg(1)=uicontrol(S.fh,'Style','toggle','String','Semester',...
    'pos',[15 250 100 25],'val',0,'visible','on');  
S.tg(2)=uicontrol(S.fh,'Style','toggle','String','Details',...
    'pos',[135 250 100 25],'val',0,'visible','on'); 
S.ed(1)=uicontrol(S.fh,'Style','edit','String','Edit Text',...
    'pos',[250 70 100 25],'visible','off');  
S.lb(1)=uicontrol(S.fh,'Style','listbox','String',{'One','Two','Three'},...
    'pos',[100 170 100 70],'visible','off'); 
S.cb(1)=uicontrol(S.fh,'Style','checkbox','Value',1,'String','Check Me',...
    'pos',[250 170 100 25],'visible','off'); 

set(S.tg(:),'callback',{@tg_call,S})


guidata(S.fh,S)
restoreState(S);

function saveState(handles)
    state2.editstr=get(S.ed(1),'String');
    state2.listval=get(S.lb(1),'value');
    state2.checkval=get(S.cb(1),'value');

    save state1.mat state2
end

function restoreState(handles)

        load 'state1.mat' 'state2'
        set(S.ed(1),'string',state2.editstr,'FontSize',12,'FontWeight','bold');
        set(S.lb(1),'value',state2.listval);
        set(S.cb(1),'value',state2.checkval);
end


function fh_crfcn(varargin)
    saveState(S)
    delete(S.fh)
end



%TOGGLE OPERATIONS
function []=tg_call(varargin)
%Toggle Operations
[h,S]=varargin{[1,3]};
if get(h,'val')==0
    set(h,'val',1)
end

switch h
    case S.tg(1)
    set(S.tg(2),'val',0)
    set(S.ed(1),'visible','on')
    set(S.lb(1),'visible','on')
    set(S.cb(1),'visible','off')
    saveState(S)
    case S.tg(2)
    set(S.tg(1),'val',0)
    set(S.cb(1),'visible','on')
    set(S.ed(1),'visible','off')
    set(S.lb(1),'visible','off')
    saveState(S)
end
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured this out and still don't know if that is the 'perfect' thing to do.

After compiling, I put the mat file state1.mat in the distr/src folder and it worked.